# how to import digital certificates in a client-server model?

Tags: java

I am trying to authenticate users in an internet banking server using netbeans.
I really need the java code for enabling them to authenticate themselves using certificates, over an SSL connection.

Thanks a lot,
G.G.

Comment: Not enough information here. Is this a web ui? What does netbeans have to do with it, it's just an IDE? Perhaps it's JSP pages?

Answer (score 0):

Look into S[pring security](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/index.html).

Comment: I am thiking of creating servlets. A client has to show his credentials(certificates) to the server. And get a response if he is authenticated or not. But What is the easiest way of doing it?Any proposals? The goal is to repsresent the authentication with dig.certificates.

Comment: Spring security is a package that allows you to set up cert authentication around a webapp, which is what would contain your servlets.

Answer (score 0):

The question can you some details, but I think you are trying to deal with certificates on the client side of the application

http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/sslguide.html